# dotnet pack include multiple projects into single NuGet package

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package

I have 3 dotnet projects under a solution A,B and C. Project A have ProjectReference in csproj file to B and C. B and C have multiple Package references to publicly available packages in their respective csproj files.

example of A.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net8.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
 

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry" Version="1.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Api" Version="1.3.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\B\B.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\C\C.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

example of B.csporj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net8.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.25.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I tried dotnet pack simply, on installation of A.nupkg, it complained that B and C are not available. Tried this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73043707/12694936, now the B and C dlls were bundled, but the dependencies of B and C were not installed. Is there any way I can make it work so that I dont have to publish B.nupkg and C.nupkg to some NuGet repository?